# check box observable not working in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi all im new to Knockout.js

And i have my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sornalingam/qxyEG/

```
var viewModel = {
    wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
    cal: ko.observableArray(),
    spamFlavors: function (place) {
        this.cal.push({ firstName : place });
    }


};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

In that if i click the checked a name it should displayed in the firstname field but its not working

can you plz help me to resolve it and suggest me some debug tools too .

Comment: Where do you source the data (like name etc.) from?

Comment: i have given it like checkbox value

Comment: Check my answer, should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qxyEG/5/

You are trying to push values into the observable array, but the checked binding is a true / false value unless you specify it's value.  Try setting the value to a property in the array and generating the options dynamically like in the fiddle I posted.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedChoices, attr: { value: $data }" />
```